# What is on topic for Role-playing Meta Stack Exchange

Tags: support, on-topic, meta

There doesn't seem to be any location to find this information, and I have a few questions that don't fit with many of the current meta questions.

Comment: Could you clarify what you're running into that isn't covered in ["what's meta?"](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta) from the Help Center? Thanks. (Oh, whoops, posted the same time SSD did. Sorry to pile on.)

Comment: (Oh, strike my last comment. I missed the “meta” in the title.)

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Your reading of my question had a duplicate: https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1000/what-is-on-topic-on-role-playing-games-stack-exchange

Comment: @nitsua60 That is the answer I was looking for, if this is reopened it would likely be the best answer.

Answer (score 7):

## Meta is for questions about the site itself

In the [Help Centre](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help) we have the article [What is "meta"? How does it work?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta). (It's in the “Our model” list, visible if you click “View more”. It starts:

> Meta Role-playing Games Stack Exchange is the part of the site where users discuss the workings and policies of RPG Stack Exchange rather than discussing role-playing games itself.

Basically, if you have a question about RPG Stack Exchange, Meta is the place to ask. Browsing the questions on Meta will give a sense of the variety of topics covered back here, and browsing the [list of meta tags](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/tags) will give another view of what categories of questions get asked & answered here.